# Awk, trying NOT to divide by zero

Tags: awk

I'm trying to divide two fields (where sometimes the divisor might be zero) with Awk.

I thought this would work: `awk -F, '{if ($6 != 0) print $3/$6}' <some file>`

But it chokes with `fatal: division by zero attempted` even though I thought the "if" condition took care not to divide if field 6 is zero.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: You could also write "awk -F, '$6 != 0 { print $3/$6 }' ...". It won't solve the problem, but it's more idiomatic awk.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"bar" != 0.  if $6 is a string, the comparison fails, but when converted to a number for the division it evaluates to zero.  Use

```
if( $6 + 0 != 0)
```

instead.

Comment: Yikes! A good reminder that awk, while wonderful for text-munging, was not designed for mathematics.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgot that about Awk as well.

Comment: That's a bug in the language or implementation. If a string which does not look like a number, such as `bar`, behaves like zero under operators like `+` opposite a numeric operand, it should also behave like zero when compared to a number using relational operators like `=`. This **could** work perfectly well, while staying in the Awk paradigm.